# Two matrix multiplication operations in CVXPY gives UNKNOWN curvature and makes the problem not DCP

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I want to solve the following optimization problem using *cvxpy*:

`Maximize(y @ A @ x)`

where A is a (n,m)-size matrix of positive valued elements;
x is boolean vector of is length m;
y is boolean vector is length n.

The constraints are:
`sum(x)==1` and `sum(y)==1`

For example, if `A = [[ 87,  96, 127,  46], [155, 166,  92,  11], [111, 163, 126, 112]]`
then the solution is:
`x = [0,1,0,0]`
`y = [0,1,0]`
resulting in: `y @ A @ x = 166`, which is the largest value given the constraints.

However, cvxpy throws an error and says:

> DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
> The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
> var27 @ [[ 87.  96. 127.  46.]
> [155. 166.  92.  11.]
> [111. 163. 126. 112.]] @ var26

The expression y @ A @ x is evaluated to Expression(UNKNOWN, NONNEGATIVE, ()), suggesting the curvature is unknown even though A @ x and y @ A are both AFFINE and NONNEGATIVE.

What is the workaround for this seemingly simple problem to make it work using *cvxpy*?

My code is:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

rows = 3
cols = 4

A = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(rows,cols))
x =  cp.Variable(cols, boolean=True)
y =  cp.Variable(rows, boolean=True)

objective = cp.Maximize(y @ A @ x)
constraints = [cp.sum(x)==1,cp.sum(y)==1]
prob = cp.Problem(objective,constraints)

prob.solve()
```

I tried doing the following to give an attribute to the randint matrix:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(rows,cols))
A = cp.Variable((rows,cols),nonneg=True)
A.value = A.project(a)
```

I tried making it a square matrix with PSD=True. Tried, pos=True.
I also tried setting prob.solve(qcp=True).
All of these still resulted in the above error message about DCP.

Comment: Sorry, as stated this is not convex. The products `x[i]*y[j]` can be linearized however (as x and y are binary variables). That would give you a linear MIP problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am afraid I am not sure how to implement this. Would you be able to further elaborate on the implementation? Thank you.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disciplined-convex-programming

Comment: How is this not just a single `argmax`?

Comment: @Reinderien It is! However, in the general problem I am optimizing beyond just y @ A @ x, so that would no longer work.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask for A and solve for B. You need to show what you actually need, or else this will be a guessing game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can linearize the problem by solving for a single variable *w* that encodes the values of *x* and *y*. Since the constraint for both *x* and *y* is that there is only 1 non-zero element and `y @ A @ x` only chooses 1 element from matrix *A* - then we can solve for `A_flat @ w`, where `A_flat` is the flattened matrix and the constraint for *w* is that there is only one non-zero element. In this way the problem can be solved using *cvxpy*. Solving for the example in the question:

```
A = np.asarray([[87,  96, 127,  46], [155, 166,  92,  11], [111, 163, 126, 112]])
Af = cp.vec(A) #Flattened into vector array

w = cp.Variable(A.size, boolean=True) #encodes x and y boolean array values

objective = cp.Maximize(Af @ w) #Equivalent to y @ A @ x

constraints = [cp.sum(w)==1] #constraint boolean array to only have only 1 non-zero value

prob = cp.Problem(objective,constraints)
prob.solve() #solve using cvxpy

xy = np.reshape(w.value,(A.shape[0],A.shape[1]),order="F")
index = np.argwhere(xy==1)
x = xy[index[0][0],:] #solution for the x boolean array
y = xy[:,index[0][1]] #solution for the y boolean array
```

Then the result is:

```
A @ w = 166.0
y @ A @ x = 166.0
```

The new formulation is equal to the old one so the problem is solved.

###### Edit: Shorter method

Similar to above, but we can reduce two lines of code by having variable *w* the same shape as matrix *A* and changing the form of the objective function to `cp.sum(cp.multiply(A,w))`:

```
w = cp.Variable(A.shape, boolean=True)

objective = cp.Maximize(cp.sum(cp.multiply(A,w)))

constraints = [cp.sum(w)==1] #constraint boolean array to only have only 1 non-zero value

prob = cp.Problem(objective,constraints)
prob.solve() #solve using cvxpy

index = np.argwhere(w.value==1)
x = w.value[index[0][0],:] #solution for the x boolean array
y = w.value[:,index[0][1]] #solution for the y boolean array
```

Answer (score 1):

### Nonlinear Optimisation

If you decide not to linearise and you're OK carrying the risk of inexact solutions for some classes of `A`, then

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint, Bounds

A = np.array([
    [ 87,  96, 127,  46],
    [155, 166,  92,  11],
    [111, 163, 126, 112],
])
n, m = A.shape


def objective(xy: np.ndarray) -> float:
    x = xy[:m]
    y = xy[-n:]
    return -y @ A @ x


Ac = np.zeros((2, m+n))
Ac[0, :m] = 1
Ac[1, -n:] = 1

x0 = np.empty(m + n)
x0[:m] = 1/m
x0[-n:] = 1/n

result = minimize(
    fun=objective, x0=x0,
    bounds=Bounds(lb=np.zeros_like(x0), ub=np.ones_like(x0)),
    constraints=LinearConstraint(A=Ac, lb=(1,1), ub=(1,1)),
)
print(result)
print('x ~', result.x[:m].round(3))
print('y ~', result.x[-n:].round(3))
print('Constraint residual:', Ac.dot(result.x) - 1)
```

```
 message: Optimization terminated successfully
 success: True
  status: 0
     fun: -166.0
       x: [ 0.000e+00  1.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00
            1.000e+00  0.000e+00]
     nit: 7
     jac: [-1.550e+02 -1.660e+02 -9.200e+01 -1.100e+01 -9.600e+01
           -1.660e+02 -1.630e+02]
    nfev: 48
    njev: 6
x ~ [0. 1. 0. 0.]
y ~ [0. 1. 0.]
Constraint residual: [0. 0.]
```

which matches your demonstrated output.

### Linear Program

Framed as a linear program,

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

A = np.array([
    ( 87,  96, 127,  46),
    (155, 166,  92,  11),
    (111, 163, 126, 112),
])
n, m = A.shape

# Objective coefficients: maximize the n*m implied products in A
c = np.full(n + m + n*m, -1)
c[:n+m] = 0

# y, x are integral
integrality = np.zeros(n + m + n*m)
integrality[:n+m] = 1

# y, x are binary; Axy vary between 0 and each A
lb = np.zeros(n + m + n*m)
ub = np.ones(n + m + n*m)
ub[n+m:] = A.ravel()

# constraints: for each Axy,  Axy <= A*y    0 <= A*y - Axy
#                             Axy <= A*x    0 <= A*x - Axy
Acy = np.repeat(np.eye(n), m, axis=0); Acy[Acy.nonzero()] = A.ravel()
Acx = np.tile(np.eye(m), (n, 1));      Acx[Acx.nonzero()] = A.ravel()
Auy = np.zeros_like(lb);               Auy[:n] = 1
Aux = np.zeros_like(lb);               Aux[n: n+m] = 1

Ac = np.vstack((
    np.hstack((Acy, np.zeros((m*n, m)), -np.eye(m*n))),
    np.hstack((np.zeros((m*n, n)), Acx, -np.eye(m*n))),
    Auy, Aux,
))
lbc = np.ones(2*m*n + 2); lbc[:-2] = 0
ubc = np.ones_like(lbc);  ubc[:-2] = np.inf

result = milp(
    c=c, integrality=integrality,
    bounds=Bounds(lb=lb, ub=ub),
    constraints=LinearConstraint(A=Ac, lb=lbc, ub=ubc),
    options={'disp': True},
)
print(result)
print('y =', result.x[:n])
print('x =', result.x[n: n+m])
print('Axy =')
print(result.x[-n*m:].reshape((n, m)))
```

```
Running HiGHS 1.2.0 [date: 2021-07-09, git hash: n/a]
Copyright (c) 2022 ERGO-Code under MIT licence terms
Presolving model
26 rows, 19 cols, 55 nonzeros
24 rows, 17 cols, 58 nonzeros
Objective function is integral with scale 1

Solving MIP model with:
   24 rows
   17 cols (5 binary, 0 integer, 12 implied int., 0 continuous)
   58 nonzeros

        Nodes      |    B&B Tree     |            Objective Bounds              |  Dynamic Constraints |       Work      
     Proc. InQueue |  Leaves   Expl. | BestBound       BestSol              Gap |   Cuts   InLp Confl. | LpIters     Time

         0       0         0   0.00%   -1292           inf                  inf        0      0      0         0     0.0s
 R       0       0         0   0.00%   -374.3333333    -96              289.93%        0      0      0        17     0.0s
 L       0       0         0   0.00%   -206.6666667    -163              26.79%       19      4      7        39     0.0s
 H       0       0         0   0.00%   -186.2666667    -166              12.21%       21      6     17        46     0.0s

40.0% inactive integer columns, restarting
Model after restart has 11 rows, 8 cols (3 bin., 0 int., 5 impl., 0 cont.), and 24 nonzeros

         0       0         0   0.00%   -186.2666667    -166              12.21%        2      0      0        56     0.0s

Solving report
  Status            Optimal
  Primal bound      -166
  Dual bound        -166
  Gap               0% (tolerance: 0.01%)
  Solution status   feasible
                    -166 (objective)
                    0 (bound viol.)
                    0 (int. viol.)
                    0 (row viol.)
  Timing            0.03 (total)
                    0.00 (presolve)
                    0.00 (postsolve)
  Nodes             1
  LP iterations     62 (total)
                    0 (strong br.)
                    29 (separation)
                    10 (heuristics)
        message: Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
        success: True
         status: 0
            fun: -165.99999999999997
              x: [ 0.000e+00  1.000e+00 ...  0.000e+00 -0.000e+00]
 mip_node_count: 1
 mip_dual_bound: -165.99999999999997
        mip_gap: 0.0
y = [ 0.  1. -0.]
x = [ 0.  1. -0.  0.]
Axy =
[[ 0.00000000e+00 -4.73695157e-15  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00]
 [-0.00000000e+00  1.66000000e+02  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00]
 [-0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00]]
```

### Direct Solution

I don't think any of the above is necessary. Since there will only be one nonzero in y and x, then

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    ( 87,  96, 127,  46),
    (155, 166,  92,  11),
    (111, 163, 126, 112),
])
n, m = A.shape
i = A.argmax()
y = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
x = np.zeros(m, dtype=int)
y[i // m] = 1
x[i % m] = 1

print(y)
print(x)
```

```
[0 1 0]
[0 1 0 0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed and thorough answer! I was looking specifically for a solution that would make cvxpy be able to solve the problem, sorry if that was not clear. It looks like your linear program approach might be adapted for cvxpy to make it work? If so, please post the answer and I can then mark it as the solution. Thanks!